# How to parse golang time

Tags: parsing, go, time

i have this dates
"25th April 2019 01:01 AM"

"11th May 2019 07:28 AM"

"26th August 2019 11:07 AM"

"31st July 2019 01:26 PM"

ETC...

my try

```
timeStr = strings.Replace(timeStr,"th","",1)
timeStr = strings.Replace(timeStr,"st","",1)
timeStr = strings.Replace(timeStr,"rd","",1)
timeStr = strings.Replace(timeStr,"nd","",1)
time.Parse("2 January 2006 15:04 PM",timeStr)
```

but this is wrong as it can remove characters from the month

Comment: Try regexp https://play.golang.org/p/PDxwzLVGWTS

Comment: @mkopriva not working https://play.golang.org/p/PbzXEUQNqmr they crop month i dont need this

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if d := timeStr[1]; d >= '0' && d <= '9' {
    // 2-digit day
    timeStr = timeStr[:2] + timeStr[4:]
} else {
    // 1-digit day
    timeStr = timeStr[:1] + timeStr[3:]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use a regexp to do such kind of things.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`^(\d{1,2})(th|st|rd|nd)`)
re.ReplaceAllString("31st July 2019 01:26 PM", "$1")
```